# Stream Feature generated from DEM is missing data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, spatial-analyst, missing-data, hydrology-toolset

I tried to search other questions to see if this has been answered but couldn't find anything, so sorry if this is redundant. I use the Hydrology toolset in Spatial Analyst to create a stream feature in ArcMap using a downloaded DEM. The series of tools I used was the following:

1. Fill (input DEM)
2. Flow Direction (input Fill)
3. Flow Accumulation (input Flow Direction)
4. Conditional > Con (input Flow Accum – input cond raster, Flow Dir input true rast & the optional)
5. Stream Order (input Con and Flow Dir)
6. Stream to feature (input Stream order & Flow Dir)
   a.  Definition query: "GRID_CODE" > 2

I am relatively happy with the outcome except in the north section of the watershed where the stream vector detail was not read correctly and only produced straight lines.

Am I missing a step that would allow this to be read properly and converted into the same level of stream detail as everywhere else in the watershed?

[image: Generated streams with DEM]

Note: The straight lines are over cropfields, residences, and timber. I included the only waterbodies on the maps because I did notice on other stream generations that open water creates "straight lines." See aerial image below.

[image: Generated streams over aerial imagery]

Comment: Those straight lines could be in a lake or a very flay area of your DEM, then you would expect these "straight rivers".

Comment: It looks like the straight lines may be an artifact of your original DEM. Do these lines follow the pattern seen in the flow accumulation?

Comment: @Hornbydd I noticed that one some other streams I generated but that is not the case here, in both images the only existing waterbodies is shown. I added another close up picture of the aerial with the stream feature to show it is mostly crops where the straight lines are.

Comment: @khafen The lines do follow the pattern generated in flow accumulation. Does that mean there is no way to fix it?

Comment: This is frequently (always?) the case with streams, esp. on a flat terrain. You need to burn some major streams along talweg, to get something better looking.

Comment: I stumbled across this PhD thesis, have a read of [section 4.5.1.4](http://etheses.whiterose.ac.uk/5452/1/Coles_2014.pdf), it gives some insight to why it happens and how they over come it using a different tool. @FelixIP you might be interested in this?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @FelixIP and @Hornbydd! I am getting admin permissions to download TauDEM because that is what they used in that thesis. Hoping that works for me as it seems promising as a simpler solution. I am not sure that I have the licenses necessary to burn in stream data, or even where to start otherwise. I will update the results if successful. Nonetheless, great to know the reasons why it is all happening.

Comment: @Hornbydd many thanks for pointer. TauDEM is totally brilliant set of tools. a) it produces much better looking results b) does it fast by using multiprocessing.

Comment: Please cut/paste your solution in the area reserved for questions out into the area reserved for answers as a self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: I used TauDEM to correct the stream network using the DEM. Below are my results. It is still not exact but it is a huge improvement and definitely usable for my work. Here is a link to a useful guide for anyone using TauDEM for their first time: http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/TauDEM51GettingStartedGuide.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Picture below shows talweg, generated by using flood depth and flow paths derived by using Hydrology tools:

[image]

As one can see flow paths depict channel shape in a well defined valleys without depressions along it. If there is one, results are random.

What is happening on a flat terrain is absolutely out of control, your pictures illustrate this nicely. So in order to get something close to reality you have to invest a lot into DEM pre-processing, e.g. burning some major waterways into it.